# self usage in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Supposed there's a model named "Person" in rails. 
I had an instance of this model person given specified id.
what does this tell me? Is this a copy of person self?

```
@person = person.person_self
```

I don't quite understand this expression.

Comment: Where you found this line ? Show more code.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `self` in rails models does not differ in any way of using `self` in any other class in Rails and Ruby on the whole.

It's all about ***scope***. Find some reading on this topic. Here is the first one [I've googled](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/15/metaprogramming-in-ruby-its-all-about-the-self/) (simple enough, decent article).